# Jquery slideToggle not opening fully after stop called

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown, slideup

I have an issue with a toggling animation with JQuery. I have a menu, which has subitems, which slide open on hover of the main item. This I can achieve fine, however, for a long list of items, I would prefer to be able to stop the opening, and slide shut the menu, without having to wait for the slideDown() animation to complete.

```
$('.menubar-topitem').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).children('.menubar-inner').stop(true).slideDown(); 
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).children('.menubar-inner').stop(true).slideUp();
});
```

This code achieves what I require, however when I then hover back over the menu item, the submenu only opens as far as the animation reached before I stopped it the first time. It seems that JQuery stores the height of the submenu from when the animation was stopped first time, and then only opens as far as this the second time.

I am aware that I can fix this problem by using stop(true,true) but that creates a horrible jump in the animation. Is there anyway I can prevent this behaviour without having to complete the animation, or any work around so that the user does not see any jumps, but instead sees a flowing menu system?

Comment: Try removing `true` from `stop(true)`.

Comment: Mmmm, I like to see questions using `.on()`.

Comment: @Purmou removing true just prevents the animation from even starting properly, instead I get a judder effect to a standstill. See the accepted answer below for the solution

Comment: I had a similar issue with a fadeIn. Used fadeTo instead which fixed it, hence I've voted the accepted answer up. The same principle fixed my issue, explicitly stating wha I needed to fade to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this is to explicitly animate hard-coded values rather than depending on the `slideUp`/`slideDown` functions:

```
$('.menubar-topitem').on('mouseenter',function(){
    var $this  = $(this),
        height = $this.children('.menubar-inner').children().height();
    $this.children('.menubar-inner').stop().animate({height : height}, 250); 
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).children('.menubar-inner').stop().animate({height : 0}, 250);
});
```

Then set the CSS `overflow` property to `hidden` for the animated elements. Also to dynamically get the height of the `.menubar-inner` elements you can nest a `div` in them and get the height of that `div` element:

HTML--

```
<div class="menubar-topitem">
    <h1>This is a Menu Top Item</h1>
    <div class="menubar-inner">
        <div>
            <p>Some Content</p>
            <p>Some More Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS--

```
.menubar-inner {
    overflow : hidden;
    height   : 0;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n6h2S/

You will run into the same problem with `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` but there is another function called `fadeTo` that allows you to explicitly set the opacity to fade to.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will do the trick. Just a couple of CSS issues I need to sort out to make it look right, but the sliding now works a treat!

Comment: Thank you, a couple of CSS changes, and it now works perfectly